# Is there a video player where I can draw on top of video?

Tags: video

I wonder if there is a video player (similar to VLC) where I could stop the video, and draw annotations on top of the video (lika on a transparent layer). Then I could choose to erase it when continuing to play the video, or leave it.

The purpose would be showing recordings of football/hockey matches. When stopping the video I could highlight players and draw tactical instructions(using the mouse).

Does such a video player exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use an app that annotates the screen? Depending on whether you are on Windows, OS X, or Linux there should be plenty of apps when you search for "screen annotate" or "annotation". Maybe you've searched for the wrong thing until now.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I immedately found Ink2Go for Mac which is 99% what I need! Will look around for tools that work on Windows too, but again, great idea!